# Restrict Special and pasted character

Tags: javascript

How can we restrict, special characters and CTRL+V from Javascript (Not JQUERY), but it should allow (-) hyphen.

Following code i have tried to restrict special character except (-) hyphen, it works well. Here i want to add a condition to restrict pasted (CNTRL+V) character.

```
function allowAlphaNumHyphen(evt){
    var keyCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
    if (((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 90 && (keyCode<58 || keyCode>64) ) || ( keyCode > 96 && keyCode <= 122 )  || keyCode==8 || keyCode==127 || keyCode==45)){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Show code and effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the above function is calling from onkeypress, it does not consider CNTR character, so new call done using onkeydown with below code

**onkeypress**

```
function allowAlphaNumHyphen(evt){
    var keyCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
             if ((((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 90 && (keyCode<58 || keyCode>64) ) || ( keyCode > 96 && keyCode <= 122 )  || keyCode==8 || keyCode==127 || keyCode==45)) && !(keyCode==17)){
            return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
}
```

**onkeydown**

```
function checkPastingChar(evt){
    var keyCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
    if((evt.ctrlKey && keyCode==86) || (evt.ctrlKey && keyCode==118)){
         return false;
    }else{
         return true;
    }

}
```